# Issue with Comobox on DataGridView

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I am using VB.NET to pull some data from an SQL database into a Datagridview.

I then want the user to be able to modify the information and save it back to the database, which I have working fine.

What I need to be able to do now is to restrict the values, but way of a combobox for the field Tarrif.

I have configured a DataSource called Tarrif1 and I am using the below code.

I have a couple of issues/questions.

Firstly the dropdown shows a single value of "System.Data.DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor" not the Tarrif1 values.

Secondly, I now have 2 columns on my datatable called Tarrif, the original database one and the one I have added - How can I get the ComboBox to right back to the appropriate Tarrif database field.

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.Common

Public Class ViewCustomersForm
  Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
  Dim connStr As String = "server=barry-laptop\SQLEXPRESS; database=BillingReferenceData; integrated security=yes"
  Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Customers"
  Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connStr)
  Dim comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Sql, conn)
  Dim dataadapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(comm)

  Private Sub ViewCustomersForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    '---open the connection and fill the dataset---
    conn.Open()
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Customers_table")
    conn.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "Customers_table"

    '---create a combobox column---
    Dim comboBoxCol As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

    '---set the header---
    comboBoxCol.HeaderText = "Tarrifs"

    '---data bind it---
    comboBoxCol.DataSource = Tarrifs1
    'comboBoxCol.DisplayMember = "Tarrif" // when I add these rows the new Tarrif column is not visible
    'comboBoxCol.ValueMember = "Tarrif" // when I add these rows the new Tarrif column is not visible

    '---add a combobox column to the DataGridView control---
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboBoxCol)

  End Sub

  Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim sqlCmdBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(dataadapter)
    sqlCmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
    dataadapter.Update(ds.Tables("Customers_table"))

  End Sub

  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

  End Sub

End Class
```

Hope that makes sense. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A few things in this code:

```
dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Customers_table")
conn.Close()
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
DataGridView1.DataMember = "Customers_table"

'---create a combobox column---
Dim comboBoxCol As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

'---set the header---
comboBoxCol.HeaderText = "Tarrifs"

'---data bind it---
comboBoxCol.DataSource = Tarrifs1
```

First, I'm not sure what happens whenever the code attempts to fill a DataSet that already has data in it. In my code, I never assume, so I always reinitialize it each time unless I need it:

```
ds = new DataSet()
```

Next, you are setting the DataSource for `comboBoxCol` as `Tarrifs1`, but I do not see that defined anywhere. You might want to look into that.

Finally, about the SQL:  `Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Customers"` I don't know what columns are in your `Customers` table. Is `Tarrif` an actual column?

Comment: @ip2code Thanks for your reply - I have added "ds = new DataSet()". With regards to Tarrifs1 being defined, it is not defined in the code, but I defined it as a DataSet in the GUI and it seems to recognise it as an object, not sure if that's acceptable? With regards to the SQL, Tarrif is one of my columns

Comment: Ok, so I have figured that I need to add a separate SQL connection to pull back the Tarrif data - But that leaves me with the issue of how to write the dropdown value back to the Customer table. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured half my issue out.

I configured a second data connection to pull the Tarrif drop down from the Tarrifs table and display this as part of the customer data table.

My outstanding issues now, is that I need to write the select Tarrif value back to the Customers table.

All the other updated values save, just not sure how to write the Tarrif dropdown back to my SQL table

Here is my latest code.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.Common

Public Class ViewCustomersForm
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
Dim connStr As String = "server=barry-laptop\SQLEXPRESS; database=BillingReferenceData; integrated security=yes"
Dim sql As String = "SELECT [Customer ID] ,[Customer Name] ,[Address] ,[City] ,[County] ,[Post Code] FROM [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[Customers]"
Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connStr)
Dim comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Sql, conn)
Dim dataadapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(comm)
Dim con As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("server=barry-laptop\SQLEXPRESS; database=Test; integrated security=yes")
Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Tarrifs"
Dim da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, con)


Private Sub ViewCustomersForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    '---open the connection and fill the dataset---
    conn.Open()
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Customers_table")
    conn.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "Customers_table"


    '---create a combobox column---
    Dim comboBoxCol As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

    '---set the header---
    comboBoxCol.HeaderText = "Tarrifs"

    '---data bind it---


    da.Fill(ds, "Tarrifs")


    comboBoxCol.DataSource = ds.Tables("Tarrifs")
    comboBoxCol.DisplayMember = "Tarrif"
    comboBoxCol.ValueMember = "Tarrif"

    '---add a combobox column to the DataGridView control---
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboBoxCol)


End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim sqlCmdBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(dataadapter)
    sqlCmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
    dataadapter.Update(ds.Tables("Customers_table"))
    dataadapter.Update(ds.Tables("Tarrifs"))

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is the database relationship between Customers and `Tarrifs`? What columns are part of `Tarrifs`?

Comment: There is no relationship. I am just using the Tariff table as a datasource for the dropdown - Do I need to configure a relationship for it to work? The Tariff table as 3 columns (tariff_id, tarrif, createdate)

Comment: No, I was trying to replicate it here, and I realized I had no idea what Tarrif went to. (by the way, it is spelled **Tariff**, or so Chrome keeps telling me every time I write it)

Comment: I am trying to write the Tariff value, back to a field called Tariff which resides in the Customer table. I am just not sure how to code that. If anyone could point me in the right direction I will be very grateful.